# Payflow reports "User authentication failed"

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, payflowpro, payflowlink

I'm trying to use the RESTful API to issue a refund and Payflow responds with "User authentication failed." I've double-checked my API user credentials and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Through trial and error, I was able to determine that the PayPal API malfunctions when the API user's password contains some non-alphanumeric characters. I solved this by making our passwords alphanumeric (only letters and numbers). PayPal Manager will not complain if you enter a password that does not completely consist of letters and numbers.

Comment: You sir are a life saver. Seriously could have never figured out this solution. No where it is documented after a months of Frustration stumbled upon your answer and now I am breathing :)